# grep % through a file

Tags: linux, grep

I am running an import job on a really large mysql file that for the most part doesn't have line breaks.

Using mysql process list I was able to fine the ID of the currently inserting record.

What I want to do is find out the character that that id appears at in the file so I can figure out what percent complete the import job is.

grep -n doesn't help because the line number isn't useful since there isn't line breaks between inserts.

Is there anything I can do with grep (or some other command) to find out how far character wise a string is in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all spaces (or semicolons or ...) with newlines and `grep` and `wc -l` the result.

```
sed -e 's/ /\n/g/' input > result
wc -l < result
grep -n "$id" result
```

If you don't want to create an additional file, call Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -e '$/ = " "; /ID/ and print "[$.]" while <>; print "$.\n"' input
```

Should output something like `[145]300`, meaning the ID appeared in the record 145 of 300.
`$/` is the record separator, `$.` is the recourd counter.

Comment: yep, I was hoping not to have to create another whole file based on it. It is a few gigs of data.

Comment: @RobKohr: Check the update.